# problem with wpf command not executing when button clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have the following XAML in a WPF application. I would like to bind the button to an `ICommand` in a view model. For some reason, I am not able to see the command from my view.
this is in a user control.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.DataContext>
        <Binding 
            x:Name="SettingsData"
            Path="Data" />
    </Grid.DataContext>
.
.
.
<DockPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <Button x:Name="SaveButton" 
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"  
                    Height="25"  
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Margin="70 0 0 0"
                    Command="{Binding Path=SaveData}"

                    >Save Changes</Button>
        </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here is my ICommand object -

```
public ICommand SaveData
{
    get
    {
        if (_saveData == null)
        {
            _saveData = new RelayCommand(
                param => this.saveData(),
                param => true
                );
        }
        return _saveData ;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why I cannot bind to this command?

Thanks for any thoughts....

Comment: What is your implementation of RelayCommand, it does not belong to the standard WPF library? I would guess that CanExecute returns false.

Comment: I am using the relaycommand implementation from Josh Smith's MVVM tutorial - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx.  the second parameter is the CanExecute, so I am always sending in true....

Comment: Can you see any binding errors in the VS Output window while debugging?

Comment: I see this in the output window - BindingExpression path error: 'SaveData' property not found on 'object' ''List`1'

Comment: Have you debugged the Binding with `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to see if everything is even working?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like you are setting the `DataContext` of the `Grid` to the `Data` property of your ViewModel (or object). If the object that the Data property exposes doesn't provide the `SaveData` command, you'll have the problem you're describing.  Remember the `DataContext` is inherited from the parent.

If you require that the `DataContext` is set in that manner, and still require the button to reference the parent `DataContext`, one option would be to use a RelativeSource to point to an element that has the ViewModel as the `DataContext`.

In WPF you also have the option of making those commands static and using the `{x:Static}` markup extension to reach it.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Here's an example if your `<Grid>` is contained in a `<UserControl>`.

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SaveData, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                          AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" ... />
```

Also, I don't know what your full XAML looks like, but I suspect that this can be simplified greatly by removing the `DataContext` on the `Grid` and Binding Data on the `ItemsControl` (or whatever you're using to show the list of objects).

Comment: The savedata command does reside in the same viewmodel that the grid is bound to.  Shouldn't it be able to see it?

Comment: No, the DataContext of the Button is ViewModel.Data, not ViewModel.  So, you're trying to bind to ViewModel.Data.SaveData. (And from your error, it seems like Data is a List of some object).

Comment: So do I have to set the datacontext of the button to the viewmodel?

Comment: Yes.  But there are methods for getting it without explicitly setting it Xaml or code, including using RelativeSource or ElementName to point to a UIElement that already has the DataContext set to the ViewModel (most likely, the parent of Grid).

Comment: The parent of the grid is the actual usercontrol.  If I set the elementname to that, I still get an error.

Comment: If I remove the datacontext from the grid as you mentioned above and put it at the list level, it works perfectly.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: thanks! i was having hard time from last couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at below error, looks like your DataContext on DockPanel is bound to some sort of List:

> I see this in the output window - BindingExpression path error:
>   'SaveData' property not found on 'object' ''List`1'

Please override Source attribute in Binding if the DataContext is not at the top level

Comment: should I set the source to the name of the viewmodel?

Comment: i usually set the DataContext in code behind. How are u setting your View's DataContext?

Comment: I set it in the xaml of the view at the grid level as shown above